# Orchestration trigger doesn't complete all the activity functions if its starts replaying

Tags: azure, azure-functions, orchestration, azure-durable-functions

I have an orchestration function which has some activities in the queue. First time it works fine and completing some activities. After few seconds orchestrator starts again with IsReplaying value 'True' but this time its not continuing the activities which are scheduled already and tasks ends here saying 'Non-Deterministic workflow detected: TaskScheduledEvent: 0 TaskScheduled '

Comment: Looks like the below opened issue:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/583

Comment: Sadly no solution provided there